# php excel file generation not working with cron job

Tags: email, phpexcel

I create a file to write an excel using phpexcel classa dne sending that via email
whileiam running tht file directly its working fine. But if i set it as a cron job its not working. I checked all the file path used in that file cant find any issue.
Checked line by line execution at that time found that if i add this two lines
that mail not sending

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('comments_excels/comments_'.$date.'.xls');
```

Comment: What is the working directory for your cron? You're trying to write a file with a relative path, but it may not be relative to where you think.... using `getcwd()` should tell you the current working directory

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like

```
$filename = getcwd().'/yourfile.txt';
```

This worked for me.